# Python: Argparse - Required AND optional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

How do I use `argparse`'s `add_argument()` function so that the user has to parse one required value and maybe parse an optional one too?

For example `--read book [page]`. You can either leave out `page` or parse a specific page you want to read. If you leave it out, it starts at page one.

I assumed this would be easy to do because I can see many tasks for it, but apparently it is not?

I am using Python 3+.

Comment: `+` is the only way to say that `--read` requires one or more arguments.  there's isn't a way of setting an upper limit.  The use of '?' for `page` uncouples `page` from `read`.  Anyways, play around with the `nargs` alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add `nargs='?'` inside the call, and the value of 1 for default (possibly also `type=int` to be parsed as number):

```
parser.add_argument('--read', dest='book', help='book to read')
parser.add_argument('page', nargs='?', default=1, type=int, help='page number')
```

Comment: `nargs='+'` is more fitting, since *book* (first argument) is actually required. + in nargs will return error in case there is not at least one argument, ? will make this case pass.

Comment: As far as I know, `nargs="?"` is used when zero or one optional argument is needed. Therefore it doesn't make sure the required value `book` is there, right?

Comment: Oh wow, I completly overlook `nargs="+"`. Is there a way to limit the optional arguments?

Comment: @kecer added use case. xvx I would assume --read book and page are different arguments (and that makes the parser easier).

Comment: @xvx You don't have to treat the book arguments as sequence - you can see them as separate, and this will store them as different entities for your use, without impact on using it (and even better, you treat page only when nonabsent).